# Regarding root space decompostion of a commuting family of diagonalizable operators on a finite dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{F}\subset \text{End}(V)$ be a commuting family of diagonalizable operators on $V$ i.e. $\forall T\in \mathcal{F}$, $T$ is diagonalizable and $\forall T_1,T_2\in\mathcal{F},\ T_1T_2=T_2T_1$.

A function $r:\mathcal{F}\to\Bbb{C}$ is said to be a root of $\mathcal{F}$ if $\exists v\ne 0$ such that $T(v)=r(T)v\ \forall T\in\mathcal{F}$.

For A function $r:\mathcal{F}\to\Bbb{C}$, define $V(r):=\{v\in V|\ T(v)=r(T)v\ \forall T\in\mathcal{F}\}$. With this notation, $r$ is a root iff $V(r)\ne 0$.

We are asked to prove-

> Keep $\mathcal{F}$ as above. Then
>
> 1. There are finitely many roots of $\mathcal{F}$ say $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_k$
> 2. $V=V(r_1)\oplus V(r_2)\oplus\cdots \oplus V(r_k)$

I know this result holds when $V$ is finite dimensional complex inner product space and $\mathcal{F}$ is a commuting family of normal operators on $V$.

In this case, I only know (from Hoffman Kunze Linear Algebra book) that $\mathcal{F}$ is simultaneously diagonalizable i.e. there exists a basis of $V$ with respect to which all elements of $\mathcal{F}$ is diagonal matrix. But I don't know prove this statement from the simultaneously diagonalizable property of $\mathcal{F}$. Can anyone give me any idea how to prove this?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What makes the version of this problem with normal operators any easier?

Comment: If you want, you could simply note that given basis that simultaneously diagonalizes the operators, if we select an inner product relative to which this basis is orthonormal, then the family is now a commuting family of normal operators.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good point to notice.